Orthogonal array of level $t$ where for any $t+1$ columns, not all $(t+1)$-tuples appear
In design theory an Orthogonal array of level $t$ is a matrix $M$ such that if one selects $t$ columns all patterns appear $\lambda$ times when restricting the matrix to these columns.
For example, in the matrix $$\begin{pmatrix}
1  & 1 & 1\\
0 & 0 & 1 \\
1 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 1 & 0 
\end{pmatrix} $$
if we pick 2 columns all $4$ patterns appear $1$ time.
Now I want such a design but the additional constraint that if I pick $t+1$ columns, all $2^{t+1}$ patterns does not appear. Having experimented with large orthogonal arrays with many more rows than columns this does not seem to hold.
I am interested in any literature on anything that could be somewhat related to this.

you need to clarify; is  what you mean is there is no choice of $t+1$ columns where all possible $2^{t+1}$ tuples appear? Please edit the question itself to make it self contained.

Yes, you are correct. Edited the questions.
